# Get format pattern directly from a Date object in Java

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I have a Date object but I don't know its format pattern. Is there some way to get the format pattern of a Date object directly from the object itself?

Comment: In what version of Java are you working? 1.8?

Comment: A Date object contains a Date, and you have the freedom to format it using various methods, `SimpleDateFormatter` being one of the many. What do you need exactly ?

Comment: for using a formatter, I have to know what pattern to use. Eg: SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy"). My question is: is it possibile to know the string "MM-dd-yyyy" directly from a date object that instatiates such pattern?

Comment: @GigiManco You use the patterns found in the java api docs to build the format string you want. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 3):

A java.util.Date object does not have an associated pattern. If you call Date.toString() it will return the Date as yyyy-mm-dd

You can also retrieve the format for a Locale by calling

```
DateFormat.getDateInstance(int,Locale)
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer of @Sergio Montoro is only half-correct. In general, you have to make a difference between value-objects (here not in sense of J. Rose working on a new value type feature in Java-10 or later) and formatters.

**A value object like `java.util.Date` can be formatted in many ways. This justifies the separation of value object and formatter.** Hence value objects have no other built-in formats than what the method `toString()` inherited from class `Object` yields. Usually this method only serves for debugging purposes in best case.

This method `toString()` however uses following format pattern (**correction of the other answer**):

> "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy"

Important to note: **This pattern itself is NOT part of the state of a `java.util.Date`-object. It is just the way how the method `toString()` works.**

Maybe your question tries to target this format which has some very serious problems however.

We can see here that this (insane) method `toString()` does not even print the whole state of the value object whose precision is in milliseconds (missing! in the pattern). Another even more confusing thing is: This special formatting method uses external context information for printing, namely the system timezone of the running JVM. This zone is NOT part of the state of `java.util.Date`.

**Conclusion:** Let's treat objects of `java.util.Date` best as without any format (meaning ignoring the method `toString()`) and always use an extra formatter like `SimpleDateFormat`.